# Checked docs on String.replace() not working anyway Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have read all the python docs on `String.replace`, yet I am still having trouble with my code. My code is as follows:

```
#within a class
def fixdata(self):
    global inputs_list
    for i in range(0, len(inputs_list)):
        inputs_list[i].replace("\n", "")
        print(inputs_list[i]) # to check output
```

What I am hoping for is that all `\n` characters (newlines) are replaced with empty string `""`so that trailing newlines are removed. `.strip()`, `.rstrip()`, and, I'm assuming, `.lstrip()` do not work.

Comment: Strings in python are immutable. You need to assign the result of `string.replace()` to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dok: [string.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

> Return **a copy of** string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

You replace and throw the copy away:

> ```
> #within a class
> def fixdata(self):
>     global inputs_list
>     for i in range(0, len(inputs_list)):
>         inputs_list[i].replace("\n", "")           # Thrown away
>         print(inputs_list[i]) # to check output
> ```

More doku:

- [lstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) /  [rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)/ [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

  > Return **a copy of** the string ...

Fix:

```
def fixdata(self):
    global inputs_list   # a global in a class-method? pass it to the class and use a member?
    inputs_list = [item.rstrip() for item in input_lists]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the new string like this:

```
inputs_list[i] = inputs_list[i].replace("\n", "")
```